# react-toolbox css config in webpack 2 not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, postcss, react-toolbox

I am working with webpack and I have been trying to config react-toolbox library.
I managed to make it work but the css is not loading.

[webpack.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5XFz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't configured your style loader to emit CSS modules

Add this to your style loader

```
loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss'
```

This will turn on CSS modules, and also set it up for allowing postCSS to hook up to it

Remember that this will now treat any `.scss` or `.css` file as a locally scoped module, so if you have any separate normal SCSS or CSS that you want to remain global, you will need to add another rule for them

// EDIT

It may be confused using the loader string if your other loader configs are still in that array (as the above string is shorthand to combine them all), try instead separately using config objects...

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader', 
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        modules: true
      }
    }, 
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          postcssNext
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

React Toolbox no longer uses SCSS having migrated to PostCSS so I've left that out - if you use it then add that in the same manner

Comment: I have tried it before but it threw
 "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'"

Comment: Loaders generally don't come bundled with webpack, you will need to have style loader installed too `npm install -D style-loader`

Comment: I have already installed css-loader and style-loader can't figure what's wrong

Comment: Updated using array that more closely matches yours